# Unable to get the built in type

Tags: python, attributes

I am trying to get a type from the `__builtins__`

```
if params.type in ["int", "long", "float"]:
     vtype = getattr( __builtins__, params.type )
     para = [vtype( para[0] )]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "message_ajax_handler.py", line 267, in get
    vtype = getattr( __builtins__, subset[i] )
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'int'
```

But when I test that in the command line

```
vtype = getattr( __builtins__, 'int' )
```

it is working. Where do I make the error.

Comment: Actual code and the code in traceback is different. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`__builtin__` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) instead:

```
import __builtin__

vtype = getattr(__builtin__, subset[i])
```

`__builtins__` (with the `s`) can either be a dictionary or the module, depending on the context. The presence of this object is actually an implementation detail. From the `__builtin__` documentation:

> **CPython implementation detail**: Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the `'s'`) made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Comment: You've still got `__builtins__` in your `getattr` :P

Comment: But why is it working by using command line and not ind the code?

Comment: @run: because in the main script (and, by extension, in the interactive interpreter prompt), you have the module itself, in imported modules the `__dict__` attribute of the module is used. Again, this is an implementation detail.